# React service worker not working?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

## Hello Guys !

Today I deployed an app online to test it but didn't understood very well why it didn't work.

### What I did :

I've created a `sample react app` using `bootstrap` and used `firebase` to deploy it. [Here is the link](https://testingsw-ebe1c.firebaseapp.com/).

### What was expected ?

I wanted the app to be able to be downloaded on the phone as [angular.io](https://angular.io/) is.

### Reality :

Nothing special. It's in fact registered in service worker and very fast to load and download, but nothing more.

### Problem now :

I've done it today two times but wasn't able to use it as well as the image of service workers I had.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a a 144px square PNG icon to be defined in your `manifest.json` to enable the web app install banner.

You can validate whether your application can be added to your homescreen from Chrome on a desktop computer.

To do so, open the Chrome developer tools on your website, open the 'Application' tab, click 'Manifest' in the left navigation and then click 'Add to homescreen'.

If there's a problem adding to homescreen an error will appear in the console, when trying it on the website you mentioned I received the error 'Site cannot be installed: a 144px square PNG icon is required, but no supplied icon meets this requirement'.

You can read more about the requirements for web app install banners here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/.

Comment: Nice ! It worked ! I've added in the `manifest.json` images from `16x16` to `512x512` and it worked well on the phone. Thank you very much